# SQL Server can we same give identity colum for two or more tables

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one qustion please helpme

Basically i have two tables `table1` and `table2`

`table1` has two columns: `id` and `name`

and data is like this

```
id      name        
c01    sukanth        
co2    ram
```

`table2` also columns `id` and `name`.

But now `table2` `id` column has to check ending number of `id` column in `table1` and start next value

Something like this

```
id      name         
c03    sukanth         
co4    ram
```

and for example if `table1` has ending column `c99`, then `table2` starting `id` is `d00` or `do1` like that

Please help me.

Here I have n number of tables but same id has to share for all tables

I want to importing Excel file data into database. I have n number of Excel files. And one Excel file one table but id should be unique for all tables. in excel file there is no id column i have to create id according to previous file ending record number

Comment: If so then, why you are using Identity column actually??? Identity Column means of no duplicate row Identifier and managed by sql server by taking care of your **Seeed value**. Use identity on Master table but, In child just use numeric column and You have to manage yourself for that.

Comment: no all are different tables. i want to load excel file data into database. i have n number of excel files.and one excel file one table but id should be unique for all tables. in excel file there is no id column i have to create id according to previous file ending record number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to manage yourself. Because SQL Server does not know about your requirement that, if one table ended with 1001 and start a new identity on another table from 1002. SQL Server Identity syntax is **IDENTITY [ ( seed , increment ) ]** Which means, each time when you insert an new row it see an Last **Seeeed** and the Increment it by the value you set up earlier while designing your table.

So, if you want to do so then, 
Insert all the rows from Excel to SQL Server. Then, Before starting to insert the rows in Next table, Get the Last **Seeed** value of previous table. Then, you can use that value to insert.

But this is very Bad Solution you know In my case what i would do is.
I just setup an Counter Variable in my application which take care of the Row Position, and i'd simply insert that Value in the Required Tables.

Anyway, you want to do that then, You can Remove that Identity Property at all. Because you self managing so.

I suggest the following way :

```
Int RowNum=0
Foreach (Excel doc){
   Foreach (Rows in doc)
     {
        RowNum++;
        Fields1=val ...n
        If data is something 
           {
               Insert into Table 1 values(RowNum,Fields...n)
           }

        If data is something else
           {
               Insert into Table 2 values(RowNum,Fields...n)
           }
     }
}
```

I think that way you can manage your soultion.

This is my suggestion only with Scratch example. Hope you understand why im suggesting you that way.

Comment: can u please  give me an example  how to use IDENTITY [ ( seed , increment ) ]  because iam new to sqlserver

Comment: Take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx Which contains all the definition and the Examples.

Comment: not like that. for example i will load one excel file today i may insert another excel file after i\one month like that n number of excel files

Answer (score 0):

So, you want your Dirty way.

This is exactly what you were looking.

Ok, take a look at this now then.

Suppose You have an table like the Following  :

```
CREATE TABLE products1 (id int IDENTITY, product varchar(40))
CREATE TABLE products2 (id int IDENTITY, product varchar(40))
```

Ok. So now you are inserting an record from Excel into your Product1 Table. Like

```
Int LastId=0

Foreach (Rows from ExcelDoc1){
    ProductName=ExcelColumn
    Insert into Products1 values(ProductName)
}
```

So now get that Last Inserted Row's Identifier so that we can use that to on another table which must be an starting ID, Like the Following :

```
LastId= Select isnull(Max(ID),0)+1 as NextId from Products1
So now you have an Last Identity on LastID

So Before Inserting an new row on the Next table
Modify that tables, Identity Insert Mode, Because you are self inserting an new Identity on that table. 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT products1 ON

Foreach (Rows from ExcelDoc2){
    ProductName=ExcelColumn
    Insert into Products1 values(LastId,ProductName)
    LastId++
} 

Again reset that Setting so that, you dont have to insert an identity value yourslef.
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT products1 OFF
```

DOne!!!

If anything Take a look at this Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Insert into Products1 values(LastId,ProductName) but we cannot insert any value in identity coulmn

Comment: Thats why you used **SET IDENTITY_INSERT products1 ON** Before inserting execute that query. I think you didnt followed by link either. Please Deeeply take a look at that Both insert Statement on above example One Like ** Insert into Products1 values(ProductName)** and another is **Insert into Products1 values(LastId,ProductName)** after SET IDENTITY_INSERT products1 ON


I think you didnt get that line either : ** So Before Inserting an new row on the Next table
Modify that tables, Identity Insert Mode, Because you are self inserting an new Identity on that table. **